# Twilio SMS 2FA in Python/Flask, server not rendering route

Tags: python, twilio, flask-sqlalchemy, twilio-api, two-factor-authentication

I am trying to implement the Twilio 2FA using a Python/Flask tutorial:

*[SMS Two-Factor Authentication with Python and Flask](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/sms-two-factor-authentication-python-flask)*

I got to the server portion and got it running.

But when I go to http://localhost:5000/ the browser displays nothing.

In the past, when I've built Flask apps in a virtualenv, I typically use the `app.run(host='0.0.0.0')` syntax where app is the Flask app.

In the tutorial, they are using the Manage method from Flask.

In the `manage.py` file where `manage.run()` is, I tried adding the `host='0.0.0.0'` but got an error saying that it doesn't recognize 'host'.

I don't really know how to make this work as I am not familiar with Manage.

I am not able to get any further as I am stuck at this point with the server not displaying the home page.

Comment: Are you starting the application with `python manage.py runserver`?

Comment: Yes I am.  I am following the tutorial using its docs from github.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `Manager`, `host='0.0.0.0'` sentence doesn't need.

You can use `Manager` when you want to define commands.

**Reference**
: https://flask-script.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

**EDIT**

If you just want to display the root, you can use `Flask` not `Manager`, so, just work as follows.

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'hello'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

`$ python main.py`

> - Running on http://localhost:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

Comment: I am not familiar with Manager and my issue is that I can't get localhost:5000 to display the route.  I am using the Twilio tutorial code and just going through it.  Not really sure how to get localhost:5000 to show up without adding host='0.0.0.0'.  Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks!  However, I am using the Twilio files and I don't think I can change it  the way you said.  The app won't work.   Twilio is using manage.run() and my question is how to add host=0.0.0.0 or do something similar so that it can run on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled the files and did the tutorial again.  This time it worked!  I am not sure why but that's fine.  I am good to go.  Thanks to you all for your help!